# Magento - module is not updating prices on a per-website basis

Tags: magento

I am having trouble with a module that is supposed to update prices on a per-website basis.

At the top of my module I have :

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

This should mean that when I call the module (the module has a frontend) I am able to update prices etc as 'admin'. However, this just isn't happening. Currently I have gone on a few desperate efforts to get it working - seeing if number formats trip it up or indexes not reindexed, cache problems and anything else.

The following snippet actually produces the right numbers but it just is not saving to the database. Any ideas?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->
           setStoreId($storeId)->setWebsiteId($websites[$store])->
           loadByAttribute('sku',$price['SKU']);
$oldprice=(float)str_replace(",","",$product->getPrice());

if($newprice!=$oldprice) {
    Mage::log($product->getPrice());
    $product->setPrice(number_format($newprice,4,".",""));
    Mage::log($product->getPrice());
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');
    $product->save();
    Mage::log($product->getPrice());
    unset($product);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that you are updating the prices of products using a method in your module's class, with the following sample code:-

```
public function updateProductPrices ($sku, $newPrice) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);

    foreach ($websites as $_eachWebsite) {
        $_websiteId = $_eachWebsite->getWebsiteId();

        $websiteObj = new Mage_Core_Model_Website();
        $websiteObj->load($_websiteId);

        $storeIds = $websiteObj->getStoreIds();

        if (count($storeIds)) {
            foreach ($storeIds as $_eachStoreId) {
                $product->setStoreId($_eachStoreId)
                        ->load($productId);

                $oldPrice = $product->getPrice();

                if ($oldPrice != $newPrice) {
                    $product->setPrice($newPrice);
                    $product->save();
                }
            }
        }

        unset($storeIds, $websiteObj, $_websiteId);
    }

    unset($product);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is an absolutely excellent answer, I eventually went for the do-it-in-mysql route making sure I did it properly (as if there can be such a thing). Big green tick for your very helpful code though!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$product->setPrice($newprice)->save();
```

Comment: Your last Mage::log($product->getPrice());, what does it write? Old or new price?

Comment: It writes the new price to the log but it does not stick when I go into admin and check the relevent store view.

Comment: How about this:
$dataarray['price'] = $newprice;
$product->setData($dataarray);
$product->save();

Comment: Nope. Now I get `Notice: Undefined index:   in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type.php on line 78` and it is exactly as per your helpful tip.

Comment: `setData()` will clear other attributes in the product, perhaps you mean `addData()` instead?

Comment: @clockworkgeek - I tried addData - no joy. This is killing me now! Three websites with different currencies, plenty of sku's to get through and it only updates the one store. Do you have any ideas on how to update from a normal module on a per-website basis? It is too far-from-obvious to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue and I think there is a bug in the answer from Knowledge Craving. The code will actually not update on a per website basis but rather update one unique price to each and every website

The bug I am talking about actually happened to me with similar code and is that other product attributes will be unlinked from default (at least, it is what happened to me).

Below is a suggestion based on Knowledge Craving's solution, I just amended a bit

```
public function updateProductPrices ($sku, $newPrice, $websiteId) {
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
$productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);


    $websiteObj = new Mage_Core_Model_Website();
    $websiteObj->load($websiteId);

    $storeIds = $websiteObj->getStoreIds();

    if (count($storeIds)) {
        foreach ($storeIds as $_eachStoreId) { //Does it need to do for each storeview, price being anyway website scope?
            $product->load($productId);

            $oldPrice = $product->getPrice();

            if ($oldPrice != $newPrice) { //actually, this if would not be necessary as you anyway want to update, right?
                $product->setStoreId($_eachStoreId)
                    ->setPrice($newPrice)
                    ->save();

            }
        }
    }

 unset($productId, $storeIds, $websiteObj, $product);
 }
```